# What is the best way to reduce assignations from DataSets to WinForm Controls

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, dataset, controls

I have several Entities like: Customer, Products, Order, OrderDetails, Employees, etc. Each one has a Window Form with CRUD Capabilities.

The problem I'm having is that I'm coding a lot of lines like this when passing data from DataSet to Controls viceversa.

```
Search()
{
 DataSet dsResult = Server.InvokeSearch();
 txtCustName.Txt = dsResult.Tables["Customer"].Rows[0]["CustName"];
 ... //like 50 columns
 txtAddress.Txt = dsResult.Tables["Customer"].Rows[0]["Address"];
}

Save()
{
 dsUpdate.Tables["Customer"].Rows[0]["CustName"] = txtCustName.Txt;
 ... //like 50 columns
 dsUpdate.Tables["Customer"].Rows[0]["Address"] = txtAddress.Txt;
Server.Update(dsUpdate);
}
```

It will ve very nice if the control has a way to retrieve the value itself if I only specify the Table.Column like:

```
txtCustName.DbColumn = "Customer.CustName";
Search()
{
mainDs = server.InvokeSearch();
}
Update()
{
server.Update(mainDs);
}
```

I'm complety lost. I have no idea what topics should search & investigate.
Any tips, help, links and examples are welcome.

Comment: Solution: start using modern technologies: WPF + MVVM + Entity Framework. Forget winforms and that magic-string-based dictionary stuff.

Comment: @HighCore Why are you providing a so heavily-opinion-based suggestion which is not backed with actual facts? (= you might prefer WPF; I do prefer Winforms). I think that this is not what SO is about. If you prefer to provide a specific answer to this question in a format which is more appealing to you, go ahead.

Comment: You might iterate through all the controls and easily perform all the assignations in a loop (directly on account of similar names between controls and tables; or via something like a Dictionary relating both sets of names). You might also rely on different approaches; like the Entity Framework (as suggested by HighCore; although he forgot to highlight that you can also use it with Winforms). There are also different types of DataBindings between controls and objects storing information (yes, in Winforms too). Lots of alternatives...

Comment: ... you are not providing enough information and your question is too generic and prone to opinion-based answers. The best way to do anything is usually what an experienced-enough person delivers on that given environment under ideal conditions (rarely something which can be easily transmitted right away to anyone). Be more specific, because this is offtopic.

Comment: @varocarbas "opinion-based", except for the fact that winforms' databinding is a joke, and, because of UWP, winforms is legacy, WPF is not ;). Also, why bother working around a legacy platform? WPF is capable of everything in winforms, plus much more. Would you go back from C# 6.0 with LINQ and async/await to C# 2.0?

Comment: @HighCore "winforms' databinding is a joke" is opinion-based. Equivalently to statements I might say about WPF, like "appearance-focused approach mostly appealing for people with web-based programming background". Why are you so interested in making everyone think like you? You are free to enjoy WPF and any other thing you wish; can the rest of the world enjoy different approaches without you feeling bothered about it? Or are you afraid that WPF (the alternative you love so much) is not being used as much as (originally, so people) expected? :) (-> just joking)

Comment: @varocarbas LOL what? winforms does not even support nested properties binding (`Person.Address.City`, for example). Also, The entire world has moved to declarative UIs. See Android, javaFX, iOS ComponentKit, you winforms people are the only ones living in the 90's still.... Go figure...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93081/discussion-between-highcore-and-varocarbas).

Answer (score 0):

Did you explore the [WinForms data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) possiblities ?
This will allow you to directly map your controls to a data source.

Comment: Ditto - Plata you seem to be "out in the weeds." There are times when we need to manually manage controls but individual lines of code seems like the worst approach. If you have a bunch of single form to single table cases use the DataSource window and use the IDE to manage the control binding and record navigation. Use WPF if eye candy is critical, otherwise WinForms is fine and easier code. Ignore HighCore posts.

Comment: Sorry, use WPF if you intend to write code that is not immediately legacy by being dependent on a legacy platform such as winforms, and which can later much more easily be ported to other platforms, due to proper separation of UI and logic, and which can be ported to Windows 10 UWP practically unmodified. Ignore @rheitzman's post.

Comment: No! Thank you! that's the startup topic I needed to know.

Answer (score 0):

Data binding is your friend. What you are asking for can be achieved with the following simple steps:

(A) Declare members

```
BindingSource bindingSource;
DataSet dataSet;
```

(B) Setup bindings

```
bindingSource = new BindingSource { DataMember = "Customer" };
txtCustName.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource, "CustName");
txtAddress.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource, "Address");
// ...
```

And you are done.

Requested usage:

```
// Search
bindingSource.DataSource = dataSet = server.InvokeSearch();

// Update
server.Update(dataSet);
```

Note how using an intermediate `BindindgSource` allows you to easy rebind all the controls to a different data source.